# how do I go about this project

Tags: c#

Hey guys I need your help.So I was making a register, everything started of nice but I kind of ran into some trouble. I'm thinking it has something to do with the `For Loop` in my code but yet again who am I to determine I'm only a beginner but anyway, I don't know how else to address the problem. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyPrograms
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the number of children present: ");
            int presentStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Please Write their names down: ");


            List <string> Students = new List<string>();

            Students.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Students.Sort();

            for (var i = presentStudents; i < Students.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i++);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: What use is `Console.WriteLine(i++);` when you are doing `for (var i = presentStudents; i < Students.Count; i++)` already?

Comment: well I'm supposed to be able to input the name of the students in accordance with the number of students given(if the number of students is 5 I should only be able to input the name of five students) but after I input one name the code stops running. I know the code might have a million mistakes, so please don't goo hard on me   I;m a big noob

Comment: You will need a loop `presentStudents` times in which you will do `Students.Add(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: You should describe `the problem`.

Comment: You run into "some problem". OK, that happens. You ask for help, that also happens. But you never explain that problem, so how would we be able to help? What do you see happening (including the exact text of error messages, if any), what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the actual problem but this will light some bulbs.

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the number of children present: ");
int presentStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

Console.WriteLine("Please Write their names down: ");
// Gathering Information
List<string> Students = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < presentStudents; i++)
{
     Console.Write($"{i+1}. Student = ");
     Students.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}

// Show Information
for (int i = 0; i < presentStudents; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. {Students[i]}");
}
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that this should solve your Problem.
The while loop checks if you have enterd the same amount of names as the presentStudents int.

What would you like to achive with the for loop ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the number of children present: ");
        int presentStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

        Console.WriteLine("Please Write their names down: ");

        List<string> Students = new List<string>();
        while (Students.Count < presentStudents)
        {
            Students.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Students.Sort();

        }
        if (Students.Count == presentStudents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for entering the Names. - " + presentStudents + " Students are present.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or can try like

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    
            Console.WriteLine("What is the number of children present: ");
            int presentStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");          

            Console.WriteLine("Please Write their names down: ");

            var studentsList = Console.ReadLine();

            List<string> Students = new List<string>();

            Students.AddRange(studentsList.Split(','));

            Students.Sort();

           
            for (var i = 0 ; i < presentStudents; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Students[i]);
            }


            // Or Try
        //for (var i = 0; i < Students.Count ; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(Students[i]);
        //}


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The try input like:
5
then
student1,student2,student3,student4,student5